# Regular expressions tool example explanation

Tags: regular-expressions, rx

Reading the section [regular expressions in EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression) appears this:

```
You can use a tool to construct regexps. For example, you can use ‘rx’ like this:

(rx (or (and "\*" (*? anything) "*/") (and "//" (*? anything) eol)))

To produce this regexp (which matches C-style multiline and single line comments):

\\*\\(?:.\\|\n\\)*?\\*/\\|//\\(?:.\\|\n\\)*?$
```

I get the `or` will match either C-style multiline or C/C++ single line comments.
But I do not get the `and` parts.

1. I am not sure how `anything` works and am assuming that will match any char.
   It might be something equivalent to `.*`. Is it?
2. If I got it right, `*?` is the non-greedy variant of `*` operation.
   Which really confuses me... The smallest possible match for `anything`?
3. Why the C-style multi-line opening is shown as **"\*"**?
   I suspect it is a typo on EmacsWiki and it should be **"/*"**.

Comment: See also the documentation for `rx` under [`(info "(elisp) Rx Notation")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual//html_node/elisp/Rx-Notation.html).

Comment: `.` matches any char *except newline*. So `.*` matches zero or more non-newline chars. `.\\|\n` matches any char (including newline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`anything` matches any character, while regexp `.` matches any character **except** a newline, the rx representation is `not-newline`.

`*?` matches zero-or-more, non-greedy. Let's extract comment from C code:

```c
/* comment */ char *s = "*/";
```

```lisp
;; * is zero-or-more, greedy
(let ((string "/* comment */ char *s = \"*/\""))
  (when (string-match (rx "/*" (* anything) "*/") string)
    (match-string 0 string)))
;; => "/* comment */ char *s = \"*/"

;; *? is zero-or-more, non-greedy
(let ((string "/* comment */ char *s = \"*/\""))
  (when (string-match (rx "/*" (*? anything) "*/") string)
    (match-string 0 string)))
;; => "/* comment */"
```

Check the doc via C-h f rx or (info "(elisp) Rx Notation").